# Very low GPU usage

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, deep-learning

I try to use single dynamic_rnn to process very long sequence for classification task.
Here are some parameters:
rnn_size=500, seq_max_length=2500, batch_size=50, embedding_size=64, softmax_size=1600.

the code is as below:

```
x_vec = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix_variable, self.x)
lstm_fw_cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = hidden_unit, input_size = word_dim)
lstm_fw_cell = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_fw_cell, output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob, input_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)
outputs, _ = rnn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=real_length, swap_memory=False)

outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
outputs = tf.unpack(outputs)

output = outputs[0]
one = tf.ones([1, hidden_unit], tf.float32)
with tf.variable_scope("output"):
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        for i in range(1, len(outputs_6)):
            ind = self.real_length < (i+1)
            ind = tf.to_float(ind)
             ind = tf.expand_dims(ind, -1)
             mat = tf.matmul(ind, one)
             output=tf.add(tf.mul(output, mat), tf.mul(outputs[i], 1.0-mat))


y_prediction = tf.matmul(output, w_h2y) + b_h2y
y_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(y_prediction)  

weight_decay = L2  * ( tf.nn.l2_loss(w_h2y) + tf.nn.l2_loss(b_h2y) )
self.cost = tf.reduce_mean( -tf.reduce_sum(self.y*tf.log(y_prediction + 1e-10)) ) + weight_decay
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(alpha).minimize(self.cost)
```

The usage of GPU on TITAN is only 5%.
The usage of CPU is about 150%.
I am not sure what's the problem.

Comment: you probably have a bottleneck somewhere, one way to find bottlenecks is timeline profiling -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yaroslav noted - this is a hard question to answer, because it requires profiling of your code (or someone lucky enough to recognize the problem).  [This comment on the github issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659) is a good starting point for profiling, as is the new [TensorFlow Performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/) page.